# Word for opposing sides in a war

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

What word would I use when describing two opposing sides in a war?

Assuming I want to refer to them in a manner similar to the following:

> Comparing/contrasting the ***_*___**'s of the war.

Using *opposing sides* lacks eloquence in my opinion. I'm also open to rewording the above so that *opposing sides* is  not needed.

Comment: I would not call *opposing sides* lacking in eloquence.

Comment: "Contrasting the opposing sides of the Peloponnesian war" seems to be a clunky title for a formal paper to me.

Comment: Really?  I would say it sounds quite good.

Comment: Perhaps it's that simple then. The first answer is often the best.

Comment: You could just say the Athenians and the Spartans.

Comment: _opposing sides_ becomes problematic if there are more than two parties involved and the alliance are not particularly clear.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I like this one: *belligerents*.

Comment: +1 This is what Wikipedia uses to list a war's participants: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_War_II

Comment: Looking further, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belligerent indicates that this is actually the UN/internationally accepted word.

Comment: In (for example) histories of WWII, the allies are sometimes referred to as "co-belligerents".

Comment: @mickeyf I thought that "co-belligerent" was used to describe nations that are _not_ allied with each other, but share a common enemy [like Finland and Germany vs USSR]

Answer (score 14):

> **opponents**

or

> **combatants**

equally include both sides in any kind of, well, opposition.

Comment: *Comparing the opponents of the war* is ambiguous, though.  Be careful that it doesn't come across as meaning *Comparing those who oppose the war*.

Comment: @drɱ65δ: good point. 'Opponents _to_ the war' is not ambiguous but it is for the meaning you give. 'Opponents _in_ the war' would be ambiguous for the original question.

Comment: Opponents seems too mild a word for war. Like they could playing table tennis.

Comment: @Sam If only they had played table tennis instead...

Comment: Combatants seems to imply the actual individuals involved in front-line fighting, as say opposed to the politicians who stand behind them.

Answer (score 12):

Adversaries is another option.

Answer (score 5):

Some options are the following ones:

- opposing forces
- opposing armies
- participants

Comment: FWIW: OpFor (short for "opposing force") is used in wargames to designate the enemy combatants being, um, simulated.

Answer (score 4):

You can use "belligerents" as in...

> Comparing and contrasting the [belligerents](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belligerent) of the war.

You can also use factions, but that usually connotes something other than nation-states fighting.

> Comparing and contrasting the warring [factions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Political_faction).

Answer (score 2):

I'm a bit late to this thread and new to this site. I hope I'm not breaking any rules by reviving this subject....

foes, adversaries, partisans

Comment: Word request answers require citations from reputable dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

Another term you could use is "opposing factions."

Comment: I think "faction" suggests the two sides are more closely related than, say, two countries, so it's applicable only in a subset of cases.